# Swift: willPresent notification completionHandler isn't working when app is inactive

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification

When I send a remote push notification when my app is inactive, the alert is shown, but the rest of the code in the completion block (a call to "doSomething()") isn't firing. It fires when the app is open, but I can't figure out why it won't when the app is inactive given the alert is still presented.

I'm using Firebase for the backend

My willPresent Method:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    doSomething("willPresent notification")

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([.alert])
}
```

doSomething():

```
func doSomething(_ senderMethod: String) {
    if let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(userId)
        let someValue = ["sent": senderMethod] as [String : AnyObject]

        userRef.updateChildValues(someValue)
    }
}
```

JSON Payload:

```
{
    "to": deviceId,
    "notification": {
                    "body": "test body",
                    "title": "Test",
                    "sound": "default"
                    },
    "priority": "high"
}
```

didFinishLaunching:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    setPushNotifications(application)

    return true
}

func setPushNotifications(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your delegate methods are in AppDelegate?

Comment: I have, the notifications are able to send/doSomething() is called when the app is running. If there's a method you'd like to see I can add it to my original post

Comment: Also, UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self needs to be set in didFinishLaunching only.

Comment: I'm setting it there, Please see editted post.

Comment: Note that if the app is not in the foreground the only delegate method that gets called is didReceive because this opens the app. So what you're seeing is expected behaviour for a background app.

Comment: But willPresent is called when the app is inactive or in the background to present the notification, would the rest of the code I put in it not be fired at the same time?

Comment: No willPresent doesn’t actually present the notification, it’s a delegate method that informs the app that the notification was presented. So what you write in willPresent only gets run when the application is in foreground.

Comment: If that's the case, why would it include a completionHandler? Solely for times the app is open? Do you know where it says this in apple's documentation I'm having trouble finding it :(